# Auothotkey prevent multiple key/button sends

Tags: autohotkey

I bought this Microsoft Scult Ergonomic mouse. When I tilt the wheel right/left, it sends multiple horizontal_wheel left/right events (keeps sending as long as its tilted), rather then just one. So I wanted to use autohotkey to prevent more then one going through per tilt. Is this possible?

Basically everytime a horizontal_wheel event comes in i want to record its time, if the consequent event is also horizontal_wheel, and is within < 70ms then block it. Even though blocked, I want to update the timestamp, so it continues to block the horintonal_wheel repetitions. I have to do it this way because when tilt is released, there is no event saying so.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should get you started:

```ahk
$WheelLeft::
$WheelRight::
    if (A_PriorHotkey != A_ThisHotkey || A_TimeSincePriorHotkey > 70) {
        send % "{" substr(A_ThisHotkey, 2) "}"
    }
    return
```

The event names might be different, check those by opening AutoHotkey window from the shell tray and switch to View -> Key history <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>K</kbd>

Comment: Thanks very much woxxom! :)

Comment: Is there anyway to ensure that `A_PriorHotkey` is the same as the previous, like if `WheelLeft` was done, to ensure that this one is also `WheelLeft`?

Comment: THanks woxxom for quick reply, I detailed my issue here with images: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows8_1-hardware/sculpt-ergonomic-mouse-rightleft-scrolltilt-is/324f8ac4-dc0d-4b1f-bb50-afda4bee030e Does this help make more clear? Excuse that I do english but not perfect at it.

Comment: It works great thanks so much, I was just having issues, because the software using mouse combintations for events. So when I hold down right mouse button, then tilt the wheel right, it doesnt block the repeats :( Because right mouse button hasnt been released yet :(

Comment: I can't test it with my mouse. Try experimenting with `$RButton & WheelRight::`

Comment: It says error invalid hotkey :( https://pbs.twimg.com/media/CT30_P5VAAAuLLe.png thats ok tahnks so much for this help Ill investigate you gave me great footing. The trigger key is not always right mouse button, I think rather the mod the mosue I should mod that software :)